# Hosting solution to avoid network issues?

Tags: web-hosting, isp

I recently went through an issue where me and all my colleagues connected to our office wifi couldn't access our website, nor could the employees at one of our customer companies. I verified that the website wasn't down, because I could still access it via proxy or my phone connected to 4G from a different provider than our office internet. Traceroute showed a request timeout after the request left my ISP's network and before reaching the server hosting my site. The problem was eventually pinpointed to a 3rd party ISP that my ISP has a peering arrangement with, and resolved.

Now it's a bit worrying that a problem like this can arise where we lose connection to our website for several days, and the problem is with neither us, our ISP or our hosting provider. We could still work with a proxy, but I couldn't very well tell our customers that they have to use one and that there's nothing we can do to solve the issue besides wait, because it's not with us. I thought the whole point of the Internet was that if one node in the network is down, traffic would get routed another way?

So my question is, what can I do to mitigate the issue should it happen again in the future? Host the website on several servers in different geographical locations? Is there a way I could then redirect the traffic if the request times out, to ensure connectivity?

Comment: I am not sure but recently I have heard that big online shop sites are mostly hosted on 2 diff. hosts so if one host down then another handle it so at  part of end customer it will be never issue like site down. so you can do something like that.

Comment: @HelpingHands: You mean like a _load balancer_? That still requires the client to be able to connect to the load balancer / front proxy which then makes the decision as to which server to use. However, this isn't a problem with the host - it's essentially a problem with the client (which is the reverse). The client somehow needs to reroute its request before it gets anywhere near the host. If the site was hosted on entirely different servers (essentially "mirrors" - different hosts) then the client could try the other host if one fails, but this is a manual action from the client end.

Comment: The problem could perhaps be alleviated by using CDNs - but what if you can't connect to the CDN? I think the problem really comes down to... Q. "If there is a problem with my corner of the internet, how do I connect to the internet?" A. Use a different connection to the internet. (?)

Comment: @w3d - Yes Might be Load balancer..

Comment: More specifically, what was the problem with the 3rd party ISP? Are you in a rural area?